# Problem with Motor Encoder - Arduino

Tags: arduino, motor, encoder, robot

I am having an issue with my motor control code.

The aim of the code is to control a motor which has a built in encoder.  Now, I wrote a simple test code that makes a user enter the value between 1-255 which makes the motor move clockwise  a certain svalue. But I am having an issue in terms of the encoder.

I used a encode library that works exceptionally well as seen in the diagram. However, when the motor moves, it does not give a real time position also seen in the diagram.

[image: Issue]

I was wondering how I can make the encoder send the Realtime position of the motor when the motor has moved.

I have attached the code below.
#include <Encoder.h>

```
//Pin Constants
#define motorDirPin 12
#define motorSpeed 3
#define encoderA 2
#define encoderB 8

Encoder myEnc(encoderA, encoderB);
long oldPosition  = -999;

//Clockwise Or Counter Clockwise
const int CW  = 1;
const int CCW = 0;
volatile long int encoder_pos = 0;



void setup()
{
  //Start Serial monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Motor Inputs
  pinMode(encoderA, INPUT);
  pinMode(encoderB, INPUT);
  //motorSetup Handles the I/O
  motorSetup();
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderA), encoder, RISING);
}

void loop()
{

  //Allows user to enter speed value between 1-255
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {

    int val = Serial.parseInt();

    //motorMove is the method that handles the motors movement.
    //Requires direction (CW or CCW)and speed paramater (Entered in Serial Monitor)
    motorMove(CW, val);
    
  }
}

void motorMove( int dir, int speed)
{
  int motor;
  int motorPinSpeed;

  motor = motorDirPin;
  motorPinSpeed = motorSpeed;


  if (speed > 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(motor, dir);// direction
    analogWrite(motorPinSpeed, speed);// speed
 
    Serial.print("speed: ");
    Serial.println(speed);
  }
  if (speed <= 0 || speed > 256)
  {
    motorStop();
  }
}

void motorSetup()
{
  //Motor Outputs
  pinMode(motorDirPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorSpeed, OUTPUT);


  digitalWrite(motorDirPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorSpeed, LOW);
}

void encoder()
{

 if(digitalRead(8) == HIGH)
  {
    encoder_pos--;
  }
  else
  {
    encoder_pos++;
  }
  if (encoder_pos == -50 || encoder_pos == 50)
  {
     motorStop();
     
     encoder_pos = 0;
     delay(5000);
  }
  Serial.println(encoder_pos);
  }

void motorStop()
{
  int motorPinSpeed;
  motorPinSpeed = motorSpeed;
  analogWrite(motorPinSpeed, 0);
  Serial.print("motor has stopped");
 
}
```

[image: Schematic]
[image: Issue]

Comment: The code misses myEnc.read() which is the crucial part.

Comment: Ive already added that to the code. long newPosition = myEnc.read();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an interrupt routine to service the encoder.  This is simpler when not using the Arduino environment, but possible even if you are.

Comment: I've added a interrput and it does do what i want. But now, im trying make the motor move and stop at a certain encoder value (which is 50). Every time a value is entered, the motor moves and stops when encoder_pos=50. However, some other values are record ater the motor has stopped. Could i add something to eliminate the unessesary values?

Comment: You're building a control loop, and it's inherently difficult.  You'll find this much easier with a stepper motor or a servo